# I am having problems with 3+ keys pressed

Tags: javascript, keypress, onkeypress

My JS mini-game don't work correctly. It only records the first two key pressed.

You can see the problem in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQprr/2/)

My code is really big, I am not sure what to put here, but I think the problem is here:

```
document.onkeypress=function(e){
    var charCode;

    e=e||window.event;

    charCode=typeof e.which=="number"?e.which:e.keyCode;

    if((charCode>=102&&charCode<=104)||charCode==106){
        getKey(charCode==106?4:charCode-101);//F-G-H-J=1-2-3-4
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Most keyboards have limits on how many simultaneous keys they can handle. Keys like shift and ctrl can often be handled on top of whatever that simultaneous limit is

Comment: @FrederickCheung if you post that as answer I would definetly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most keyboards have limits on how many simultaneous keys they can handle. Keys like shift and ctrl can often be handled on top of whatever that simultaneous limit is.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onkeydown` to track when a key is pressed, and `onkeyup` when a key is released. You might track which ones are currently pressed in an array or something.

EDIT: Nevermind. Your game worked fine for me with up to four keypresses. Your commenter was on to something; I think your keyboard just can't handle it.

Comment: But when any two keys are pressed, the third is not even recorded

Comment: Did you try onkeydown as well as onkeypress?

Comment: Oops. I missread your `onkeydown`. I will check that and see what happens. EDIT: I don't know how to use `onkeydown`, I tried to use it, but it don't work and it prevents me to use F5 to refresh

Comment: Edited my answer. Could be your browser too; I used FF9.